# How to override lookup icon in standard page layout

Tags: page-layout, lookup, button-overrides

We need to override lookup icon in standard page layout and customize logic by ourselves. Anybody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, we need to override lookup icon in standard page layout and customize logic by ourselves. We can inject javascript into standard page and override something you want!

- Step1, Create a home component which's type is html area, we can put override javascript in there,
- Step2, Put html area you created in salesforce sidebar(Narrow).
- Step3, If everything is ok, your lookup icon will be override successfully! But don't get too excited, we will encounter CSRF protection when we use window.opener.getElementById function. Fortunately, we can solve this by window.postMessage method, then add listener in your html area component.

The key is javascript which override specified lookup icon and avoid CSRF protection, please check the below code( Please note that, the below "Organization Role" means the label of lookup field and we find lookup icon you want to override by it),

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script>
    var jq$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    var timer;
    jq$(document).ready(function(){
        //add listener to receive data from popup window and avoid CSRF protection.
        window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            var message = e.data;
            if (message != null && message != undefined && message.split('|').length == 2) {
                var selectedName = message.split('|')[0];
                var selectedId = message.split('|')[1];
                var orgRoleId = jq$("label").filter(function(index){ if(jq$(this).contents(':not(span)').text()=="Organization Role") return this; }).attr("for");
                jq$("input[id=" + orgRoleId + "]").val(selectedName);
                jq$("input[id=" + orgRoleId + "_lkold]").val(selectedName);
                jq$("input[id=" + orgRoleId + "_lkid]").val(selectedId);
                jq$("input[id=" + orgRoleId + "_mod]").val(1);
            };
        });

        //Looping execution until overriding lookup.
        timer = setInterval(function(){
            var orgRoleId = jq$("label").filter(function(index){ if(jq$(this).contents(':not(span)').text()=="Organization Role") return this; }).attr("for");
            if (orgRoleId != 'undefined' && orgRoleId != null){
                var orgRoleLookupLink = jq$("a").filter("[id^=" + orgRoleId + "]");
                if(orgRoleLookupLink != 'undefined' && orgRoleLookupLink != null){
                    orgRoleLookupLink.attr("href","#").attr("onclick", "window.open('/apex/OrgRole?retUrl=' + window.location.host, '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=500, width=600, height=600')");
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }
        }, 100);

        //Hide html area component.
        var timer2 = setInterval(function(){
            jq$("h2.brandPrimaryFgr").each(function(){
                if(jq$(this).text() == 'OverrideOrgRoleLookupIcon'){
                    jq$(this).parent("div").parent().hide();
                    clearInterval(timer2);
                }
            });
        }, 100);
    });
</script >
```

Comment: Note that Salesforce are heading towards blocking this sort of code - see [End of javascript sidebar hacks?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-hacks).