# Hide custom button in Standard Pagelayout

Tags: page-layout, home-page-component

I know that we can hide the standard page button using HTML area home page component. But as per summer 14 release, unsupported html, javascript functions will be disabled from summer 15 and old components will work till then. so i do not want use this approach.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_home_page_components.htm

May i know is there any other work around to hide the custom button in standard page layout.

Edit:  answer is here [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-hacks)

Comment: No probs :) I was really happy when I found that answer myself some time ago. Which is in a way a bit sad, we developers really need this "hack"...