# Is there a way to use JavaScript on Home Page Components?

Tags: javascript, home-page-component

We can see that the support for JavaScript on home page components is being phased out as described here:

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_home_page_components.htm

Is there an alternative to add java script on a homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are going to do:

**Use Case 1**

If you just need a homepage component which uses JavaScript and have the access of JavaScript limited to the **component itself** then you should use the new HTML Area Home Page Components: 
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_home_page_components.htm

**Use Case 2**

If you need your JavaScript to access the **entire homepage** and/or other pages where the sidebar is available, you can have a look at the workaround described here [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-hacks) which is working at least in summer'14. This would apply mostly to use cases discussed here [Why do we still need to hack the Sidebar? Usecases - Workarounds - Alternatives](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44971/why-people-still-need-javascript-sidebar-workarounds-and-what-alternatives-could?lq=1) please mind, that these approaches may also be discontinued at some point in the future by Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to create a visualforce component and put your Javascript in there instead.