# How to Add HTML / Javascript / Jquery "Slide Out" Tab (Globally)

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html

- I have a form that displays when a user selects a tab
- This form slides out when selected, and hides itself when selected again
- The action to display / hide is javascript / jquery
- I'd like this form to be globally visible from any page within Salesforce.com
- Here's a link to the type of form I'm describing: http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

Questions:

- As with the link, the form is HTML and Javascript:
- So attempted to deploy as a Homepage Component (HTML), and came up blank
- Then attempted to deploy as a Homepage Component (VF), but displayed within it's own box
- Would I need to make a VF Page that's globally accessible?
- Would it be possible to overlay this tab everywhere within Salesforce, and not just the homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to add custom JavaScript, HTML or CSS globally to Standard Pages. Salesforce does not support or encourage developers to interaction directly with their markup or JavaScript on Standard Pages. They reserve their right to make unannounced changes to the HTML, CSS and JS which may break your implementations on that deep level.

**So generally it is not a good idea to do it.**

This caveat emptor expressed, there are approaches to help your self if you are willing to accept the risks that your solution will stop to work at some day in the future.

Please have a look at this: [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds/41840#41840)

If you follow the steps carefully, it will let you run custom JavaScript in some (not all) Standard Pages. You will probably have to adjust your existing code to work properly.

And for some use cases at that:
[Why do we still need to hack the Sidebar? Usecases - Workarounds - Alternatives](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44971/why-people-still-need-javascript-sidebar-workarounds-and-what-alternatives-could?lq=1)