# Filtering in Related List

Tags: related-list, filters

We are looking for a Filtering option in the Related Lists. As We understand, there is NO Out of the Box or configuration mechanism in SFDC to filter the Related Lists. (Though we have Sorting Option available, that too for a single field). Hence, derived the following two possibilities to achieve this requirement:

- Create an inline Visualforce page (that is embedded within a standard page layout) to create the effect of a filtered Related List.  This would embed a query to only show the values you want.
- Use of some Productivity AppExchange Tool like MiniGrid (app by Configero) which enable filtering on Related Lists in Page Layouts. MiniGrid although is a paid app.

Any other easy solutions possible here please ?

Comment: There is a [Lookup Filter](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_examples.htm&language=en_US) mechanism available that constrains the child objects included in a relationship. Probably doesn't meet your needs, but worth reviewing if you haven't already.

Comment: Actually your two options are one and the same under the hood: mimigrid **is** a visualforce page embedded on the layout. From the UX standpoint both solutions may suffer by the platform limitation of embedded pages to have a fixed height in pixels. If you have many lineitems you end up with scrollbars inside scrollbars http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44971/why-people-still-need-javascript-sidebar-workarounds-and-what-alternatives-could

Answer (score 1):

Just another note re inline Visualforce pages... They don't align with regular related lists so look terrible and users are generally not accepting.

Things I do is create a report linked from a custom link on the page, with common used filters; Add a chart on the page layout to show a bar chart with a count of records in each category; or train the users to click on the more link and use the sorting functions there.

That said, you can always look at Skuid and Grid Buddy to see if either of these apps are useful to you.