# Access the edit page buttons from visualforce area home page component

Tags: javascript, visualforce-component, jquery

After Summer'15 release the html area home page components with java script is not going to work. So we are using visual force area component. I am trying to rename Save button in all standard page layouts to "Submit", using java script DOM.To get the element, we used "window.top.document.getElementsByName". Now this line is not working from VF page that is used in the Home Page Component(Visual Force Area). Please suggest Jquery/JS that will retrieve the element out side the VF page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per release notes: it is cleary mentioned :

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_home_page_components.htm

> Visualforce Area home page components can be added to the narrow or the wide column of the home page layout, and the referenced Visualforce page can use a standard or custom controller. You can include JavaScript in your Visualforce page, but because the component is rendered in an iframe on the home page layout, t**he JavaScript can’t interact with the page that contains the component**.

Seems like SFDC has taken off the ability to run javascript to access Home page components. You can refer following other posts/discussion around this topic

[Why do we still need to hack the Sidebar? Usecases - Workarounds - Alternatives](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44971/why-do-we-still-need-to-hack-the-sidebar-usecases-workarounds-alternatives?lq=1)

This one clearly provided 'alternative' which could help you to achieve what your're looking for:

[End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)

Comment: But using window.top.document we can communicate with outer page from iframe right? It's happening from HtmlArea, but not from VF Page.
Previously the HTML Area component is accepting to edit HTMl, but now it will accept only rich text, images. Not HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much @Curious_techy.  It's worked superbly.