# Visualforce Dynamic Resizing

Tags: visualforce

Hi Visualforce experts:

Is it possible to dynamically resize a Visualforce Page based on a specific condition?  For example, on my page - warning #2 is displayed only when a condition is met.

If this condition is not met, the warning is not shown.

Warning #1 is always static/does not change.

I would like to essentially resize my page when the condition is not met.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"
extensions="OpportunityControllerExtension">

<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.alerts}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.infoIcon}"/>

<warning>
<img src="{!$Resource.infoIcon}" border="0"/> 
<apex:outputLabel value="Opportunities may be submitted for Approval and/or    
Resource Assignment at Stage 3 or later.">
</apex:outputLabel> 
</warning>

<apex:form rendered="{!Opportunity.Account.NumberOfEmployees == 0}">

<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.alerts}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.infoIcon}"/>

<warning>
<img src="{!$Resource.infoIcon}"border="0"/> 
<apex:outputLabel value="Please populate the Number of Employees on the "><a   

href="/{!opportunity.AccountId}/e?retURL={!opportunity.Id}" title = "Click   
here to go Edit the Account" target="_blank">{!opportunity.Account.Name}</a>   
Account before moving forward.
</apex:outputLabel>      
</warning>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is nothing we can do for this in regard of Visualforce. The behaviour is based on the height you have provided when you embed the Visualforce page in the standard page layout.

Comment: This functionality is no longer possible to implement as of Winter16. You can see how it *used* to be possible here: [Why do we still need to hack the Sidebar? Usecases - Workarounds - Alternatives](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44971/why-do-we-still-need-to-hack-the-sidebar-usecases-workarounds-alternatives)

Comment: See also: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds

Comment: That's unfortunate!  @AdrianLarson

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. The Lightning UI is supposed to address some of the reasons we needed sidebar hacks in the first place, but it is a steeper learning curve and a big change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is *no longer possible* since Salesforce stopped allowing sidebar javascript.