# Resize Visualforce Page Component on Account Page Layout

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, account, page-layout

I have the below `Visualforce Page` component. It works properly but I would like to make it larger on the `Account Page Layout`. I would like to increase the height on it, but am not sure how to accomplish that.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:iframe src="myURL" scrolling="true" id="theFrame"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Do you mean dynamically, or just to resize it at all?

Comment: Dynamically, it hasn't been supported for a while now. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44971/why-do-we-still-need-to-hack-the-sidebar-usecases-workarounds-alternatives

Comment: It doesn't need to be dynamically. I just want to increase the height to 800px and it always be that large

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When editing the `Page Layout`, you will see a wrench icon as part of the `Visualforce Page` component:

[image: Wrench Icon]

When you click that, you'll get a menu that allows you to change the height:

[image: Visualforce Page Properties]

Comment: Adrian. You are amazing lol. Thank you so much! Can't believe I didn't think of that lol.