# Where is the LockerService API Viewer gone?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

It was here

http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureWindow.app?aura.mode=DEV

but this URL is broken now.

Where is it gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Salesforce has moved it without forwarding the old url. Now you can find it here

http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV

Comment: Did you mean here? http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV

Comment: @MartinLezer thanks you were right: bad copy paste with my mobile phone... Fixed above in the answer. Salesforce should redirect in such cases.

Comment: For some reason, none of the URL are working for me?

Comment: Can Happen @RahulSharma that DNS propagation /redirection isn't complete

Comment: We are adding the redirects! Apologies for the omission.

Comment: @JFParadis check your server... https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewAlert.x?alertId=55343
Seems like you might be running vulnerable version http://auraframework.org/arcgis/admin/

Comment: Thanks @dhz for your report. The relevant parties have been notified. Please PM me if you have more details.

Comment: looks like its dead again