# Need to remove the New Task and New Event Button from only the Home page

Tags: custom, home-page-component

I need to remove the New Task and New Event Button from only the Home page.
I have found a way of using a Javascript and using Custom links, but the Custom link ends up appearing in the sidebar in Home page. How do I restrict that?
Or is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the Custom Links (or even their container) in the sidebar again using JavaScript. Use Firebug to figure out the right selectors. If you want to do it easily and most convenient, include also jquery and use the .hide() method.

Please remember that this workarounds might break in future releases of Salesforce according to the statements by Robert Sussland here: [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)

Please note, that using this method, the links might appear for a very short time on page load and will be hidden a few seconds later. Even this can be avoided and you can read on here: [Disable custom list button if no object selected](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45281/disable-custom-list-button-if-no-object-selected/45285#45285) (there the comments in the bottom)