# Hiding 'Edit' action of a related list

Tags: related-list

Wanted to hide the 'Edit' action from one of my related list.

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this by out of the box.

-

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one out of the box, except **not granting Edit permissions** to that object.

You could **override** the Edit button with some Visualforce page, but in that case it redirects for all Edit buttons for that object.

You could also have a **sidebar hack using Javascript**, but those will [no longer be supported](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds).

Comment: hmm....
i tired permission granting but it is not working because salesforce does not allow to uncheck the only edit option, it also uncheck the delete option.


Thanks Robin for your reply.

Comment: That is expected behavior, you cannot have delete rights without edit rights.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to remove the Edit access at the object level for that user. 
Thus the user will not be able to see edit button/link on the related list as he is not having edit access on the object.