# Is it possible to add custom javascript to the create (standard) object page

Tags: javascript, standard-objects

While looking i found out i can overwrite parts of the case feeds page. 
Source: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide.pdf

But is this also possible to change the create object page? I would like to add my custom javascript for the the textareas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a topic that uses the sidebar to achieve this.
source: [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)

Worked like a charm.