# Visual force page that filters a report

Tags: visualforce, joined-reports

In Summer 15 our little HTML hacks will be going away and we will all need to make VF Pages in order to continue to make people happy.  On my home page I have a custom component that looks like this

```
<form method="get" action="https://--.my.salesforce.com/00OE0000002bwa5">Status: <input  
name="pv0"><br>Design End Customer: <input name="pv1"><br>Product: <input name="pv2">
<br>Production Customer: <input name="pv3"><br>Zip Key: <input name="pv4"><br><input 
value="Search" type="submit"><br><br></form>
```

Now I know I don't need a controller but I am unsure how to go forward, how would I go about passing values to a report?  I don't want to use a controller, I want to simply take the input that they put in the InputText/Fields and then point it to the a filterd Report... I'm not sure how to do this

This is what I started, don't know if I'm even going in the right direction.

```
 <apex:page>  
 <apex:form >  
 <apex:pageBlock title = "Opportunity Part" mode = "edit">
  <apex:inputText value="pv0" id="designEndCustomer" label = "Design End Customer"/>
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>  
 </apex:page>
```

The follow is the warning that I am seeing

> This component contains code that is no longer supported. For security
>   reasons, in Summer '15 we will start removing non-supported code from
>   HTML Area home page components. As a result, this component may stop
>   working properly.
>
> If you want to use JavaScript or other advanced HTML elements in your
>   home page component, we recommend that you create a Visualforce Area
>   component instead.

Comment: You mean URL hacks?  Where did it say they're going away in Summer 15?

Comment: @Jagular Updated my question

Comment: I think this may be been answered here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds

Comment: No, This is not the same situation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 99% of cases, you just need to slap an `apex:page` tag around the original content and carry on. Note that you will now be in an iframe, so you need to target the top-level browsing context to break out of the little box you'll find yourself in.

```
<apex:page>
    <form target="_top" method="get" action="https://--.my.salesforce.com/00OE0000002bwa5">
       Status: <input name="pv0"><br>
       Design End Customer: <input name="pv1"><br>
       Product: <input name="pv2"><br>
       Production Customer: <input name="pv3"><br>
       Zip Key: <input name="pv4"><br>
       <input value="Search" type="submit"><br><br>
    </form>
</page>
```