# Code For Auto Refreshing Dashboards

Tags: dashboard, refresh

Referring to this code here:

```
var run; 
  function refresh() { 
     var dashboardButton = document.getElementById('db_ref_btn'); 
     dashboardButton.click() 
  } 
  window.onload = setInterval(refresh);
```

We have a Professional Edition org and and Enterprise Org ...and assuming we are unable to refresh with standard refresh provided in our Enterprise Edition org,

How can you specify which dashboards are being refreshed? We'd like to refresh all 6 of our dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

This depends much on where you want to do that. On visualforce pages your method could work, but on standard pages there is no official way to include your JS.

However if you are somewhere where you can place a button/link or have the sidebar available, you could use REQUIRESCRIPT similar to that approach here:

[End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)

Note that you wouldn't need to click the link/button. Your script will be invoked just on pageload.