# How to fill my lookup field every time I create a new Timecard?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an object Timecard i.e **pse__Timecard_Header__c** and a lookup field  PD i.e. **PD__c** which is related to another object called Period i.e. **c2g__codaPeriod__c**. I want to fill this lookup field every time I create a new Timecard.

Comment: do you always want to fill the lookup field with the same parent object?

Comment: yes, I always want to

Answer (score 0):

One could create a custom button which loads a visualforce page.  This visualforce page constructs a custom url which passes the field Id and value as querystring parameters to the TimeCard creation page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have New overridden by a Visualforce page at "Buttons, Links and Actions" you can set the value in the constructor of your controller. You should be able to prepopulate any values there as you like. I think this is a best practice in cases like this.

Or you can use javascript to inject any value into the lookup text field. I like to use jquery for stuff like that. If it's a match to something existing which is unique, it will be saved if you press save without further question. If you don't have unique names, you may end up with an intermediate page.

If you have not overridden New and don't want to, it's not so easy. As @BenjaminPirih said, you could try it with URL params, or you could inject a custom JavaScript into the standard page. Unfortunately this would require to use a workaround as described here: [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds) - please mind that this approach might break in the future.

Comment: in your overridden link you can build the url as so.. 

http://www.bulkified.com/article/?articleid=18  then pass additional nooverride=1 to get back to standard layout..  Good answer! 

http://help.skuidify.com/m/page-assignments-and-overrides/l/102550-how-do-i-get-back-to-a-standard-salesforce-layout-when-i-ve-already-overridden-it

Answer (score -1):

This trigger will populate the lookup field:

```
trigger MyTrigger on pse__Timecard_Header__c (before insert) {
    c2g__codaPeriod__c cp = [select Id from c2g__codaPeriod__c where ??? limit 1];
    for (pse__Timecard_Header__c th : Trigger.new) {
        th.PD__c = cp.Id;
    }
}
```

This assumes you want to query for the c2g__codaPeriod__c ID (based on some where clause instead of the ??? I've included) rather than hard-code it.

Comment: This will override any value that has been set by the user during the creation screen..

Comment: @Keith  here you are assign one single period to all the timecards in trigger.new but those timecards may have different periods

Comment: @sus Can you add more explanation to the question then; the question and comments combined read like its a single value. Is there some value on the timecard that allows the correct period to be looked up?

Comment: @BenjaminPirih The question/comments as written right now answers "yes, I always want to" to the question "do you always want to fill the lookup field with the same parent object". Nothing about allowing a user to enter a value on a creation screen.

Comment: "I want to fill this lookup field every time I create a new Timecard."  is much different than "yes, I always want to.."   :)  best of luck!