# End of Sidebar workarounds via Messages & Alerts and Custom Links finally in Winter or Spring '16?

Tags: javascript, home-page-component

There was an update in a partner alert about the HTML home page components on February 27th. Now two sentences has been added to this paragraph:

> With the Summer '15 release*, Salesforce will no longer support markup
>   that fails the whitelist filter. Any unsupported content will be
>   removed prior to rendering the page. **In addition, the Messages &
>   Alerts and Custom Links components will be rewritten and will not
>   include the HTML Home Page Components. We will be phasing these out in
>   Winter ’16.**

These sentences are a bit confusing, since  HTML Home Page Components were never included in Messages & Alerts and Custom Links.

It would be helpful to get further clarification on this. What exactly will be changed?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this means that Messages & Alerts and Custom Links will be rewritten and filter out unsupported markup and JavaScript. Another interpretation could be that the Messages & Alerts and Custom Links Components will be removed at all.

This would also align with the explanations from Robert Sussland here   [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)

As a result all Sidebar workarounds might no longer be possible using the patterns discussed in the question above.

Comment: With the release of Winter '16 to sandboxes now, have you been able to determine whether this is true?  Is there a way to automatically execute javascript in the sidebar?

Comment: It seems that with Winter'16 the REQUIRESCRIPT function does not work as reliable as before - at least on one Org I can reproduce it. Will let you know as soon I checked in other Orgs. On the Org where it did not work anymore I used Messages&Alerts as a workaround - but be aware that even this will be shutdown soon as described in my second answer.

Answer (score 3):

Now there is official information from Salesforce about this. They will kill this workaround with the Spring '16 Release, which is currently trageted for February 2016.

**Email from Salesforce**

Admins of Orgs which are using this technique should receive an email like this:

> **ATTENTION: Messages & Alerts and Custom Link Components Changes**
>
> At Salesforce, trust is our #1 value and our priority is to provide
>   customers with the industry’s highest levels of security,
>   availability, and performance. With that in mind, we want to notify
>   you of an important change regarding certain home page components that
>   your organization has used.
>
> **What is changing?**
>
> The Salesforce Technology team is updating code
>   within the standard Messages & Alerts and Custom Links home page
>   components, including JavaScript and custom HTML markup to comply with
>   our evolving security architecture best practices. These changes will
>   enhance the security of your organization.
>
> **How will this affect my organization?**
>
> With the Spring ‘16 release*,
>   Salesforce will no longer support code in Messages & Alerts or Custom
>   Links that is not whitelisted. Any unsupported content will be removed
>   prior to rendering the page. This may affect your organization, and we
>   strongly encourage you to plan accordingly to remove any unsupported
>   content in advance.
>
> *Currently targeted for February 2016; date subject to change
>
> **What do you recommend?**
>
> If you wish to continue using these features,
>   we encourage you to migrate to Visualforce Area home page components,
>   which offer more flexibility and security. These point to a
>   Visualforce page, rendered in an iframe in the home page layout.
>   Alternatively, you can remove or update code that does not pass the
>   markup whitelist.
>
> Note: JavaScript in the Visualforce Area home page component will not
>   be able to interact with standard pages that contain the component.
>
> How can I get more information?
>
> Please see the Message & Alerts and
>   Custom Links Home Page Components changes article for more details.
>   For additional questions, please reach out to Customer Support by
>   opening a case via the Help & Training portal.

**Knowledge Article 000229719**

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Message-Alerts-and-Custom-Links-Home-Page-Components-changes&language=en_US&eid=singlesend&d=70130000000NIyh

> 1. What is changing and when is the change?
>
>    With the Spring ‘16 release*, changes will be made to better align standard Messages & Alerts and Custom Links home page components
>      markup to comply with our evolving security architecture best
>      practices and we will end support for non-whitelisted content.
>
>    These changes will provide more flexibility in your components and enhance the security of your organization.
>
>    At runtime, standard Messages & Alerts and Custom Links home page components with non-whitelisted markup will no longer be rendered in
>      the page.
>
> *Currently targeted for February 2016; date subject to change
>
> 2. What action do I need to take?
>
> If you wish to continue using these features, we encourage you to migrate to Visualforce Area home page components, which offer more
>   flexibility and security. You can either move the HTML markup to a
>   Visualforce Area component or remove code that does not pass the
>   markup whitelist.
>
> 3. What are Visualforce Area home page components?
>
> Visualforce Area home page components have been available since the Summer ‘14 release. These point to a Visualforce page rendered in
>   an iframe in the home page layout. The iframe takes the full width of
>   the column (narrow or wide) but users specify the height.
>
> Some information about the containing page is passed into the Visualforce page: see #5, How do Visualforce home page components
>   work?
>
> 4. How will I know if there is JavaScript in standard Messages & Alerts and Custom Links home page components?
>
> If you have customized the standard Messages & Alerts or Custom Links home page components with HTML code, you will need to manually
>   review the inserted code to look for the presence of Javascript with a
>    tag or other methods, such as onclick(). To manually review
>   the inserted code, follow these steps:
>
> 1) From Setup, click Customize > Home > Home Page Components. Click
>   Edit next to either Messages & Alerts or Custom Links; both components
>   need review and are in the Standard Components related list.
>
> Example of Home Page Components page: 
>   [image: Screenshot 1]
>
> 2)  Review the text for HTML code. If the text is plain text, there is
>   no action necessary.
>
> 3)   If HTML code is present in the text, use the browser search
>   capabilities to search the text block for offending content with a
>   `<script>` or other methods, such as onclick(). If you find any
>   offending content, either you will need to remove it or replace the
>   entire component with a Visualforce component.
>
> Example of Message & Alerts page with offending content: 
>   [image: Screenshot 2]
>
> Example of Custom Links page: 
>   [image: Screenshot 3]
>
> b. An example of acceptable content in the Bookmark fields in standard
>   Custom Links components is as follows:
>
> Bookmark = Salesforce Success Community
>
> URL = https://success.salesforce.com/
>
> If you have manually entered offending content in the Bookmark
>   fields in standard Custom Links components Javascript with a 
>   tag or other methods, such as onclick(), either you will need to
>   remove it or replace the entire component with a Visualforce
>   component.
>
> 5. How do Visualforce home page components work?
>
>    - Visualforce home page components allow you to specify a Visualforce
>        page to show on either the home page or in the sidebar on other pages.
>        Visualforce home page components:
>    - Can be added to the narrow or wide column of the home page layout.
>    - Can use a standard or custom controller.
>
> Are rendered in an iframe in the home page layout. The iframe takes the full width of the column (narrow or wide); you specify the
>   height at design time.
>
> Sometimes receive information as query string parameters, allowing the Visualforce page to display information specific to the top-level
>   page:
>
> - The path of the top-level page
> - The ID of the record, if the Visualforce home page component is in the narrow column and included in all pages
> - May contain JavaScript, but the JavaScript will not be able to interact with the page containing the iframe as Visualforce pages are
>     served on a different domain.
>
>   6. Based on the record/tab I'm viewing, can I use a Visualforce home page component to render different information in the sidebar?
>
> Yes, as long as the rendered content is contained within the iframe in
>   the sidebar. For example, if you have a list of links that change
>   depending on whether you're viewing an account or an opportunity, then
>   you can use a Visualforce home page component.
>
> 7. Can I use a Visualforce home page component that shows up in the sidebar for some pages, but not others?
>
> No, you can choose to have sidebar components display only on the home
>   page or display on all pages in the User Interface settings. But if
>   the component displays on all pages, then it displays on all pages --
>   for example, there's no way to display it only on record detail pages.
>
> 8. Can I use JavaScript in a Visualforce home page component?
>
> Yes, Visualforce pages used in home page components have no additional
>   restrictions compared to Visualforce pages used in tabs (see Using
>   JavaScript in Visualforce Pages in Help & Training). However, the
>   JavaScript cannot interact with elements outside the iframe.
>
> 9. On a record detail page, can I use JavaScript in a Visualforce home page component to hide or show content?
>
> No, Visualforce pages are served on a different domain and are
>   rendered in an iframe. They cannot interact with pages served in the
>   Salesforce domain.
>
> 10. If I’d like to change the style of headings or other elements in a record detail page, can I use JavaScript in a Visualforce home page
>       component?
>
> No, Visualforce pages are served on a different domain and are
>   rendered in an iframe. They cannot interact with pages served in the
>   Salesforce domain.
>
> 11. What happens if my standard Messages & Alerts and Custom Links home page components used an iframe to point to a page that's not a
>       Visualforce page?
>
> These components will not allow iframes as part of the whitelisted
>   markup. You can create a Visualforce home page component and redirect
>   to another page from within the Visualforce page.
>
> 12. I have customized Salesforce to leverage JavaScript in standard Messages & Alerts and Custom Links home page components, and this
>       change is going to eliminate a lot of my customizations. How can I
>       avoid eliminating my customizations?
>
> We realize that this change may cause inconvenience for you, yet you
>   will not be able to avoid the customizations from being eliminated.
>   This notice should provide time to replace standard Messages & Alerts
>   and Custom Links home page components with Visualforce home page
>   components. Salesforce does not recommend or support the use of
>   JavaScript in home page components (and never has) -- particularly if
>   the JavaScript is used to interact with markup served by Salesforce,
>   because we can't guarantee that our page markup will remain the same
>   between releases.