# Is it possible to customize the standard Logout link in Salesforce?

Tags: logout

Is it possible to customize the standard Logout link in Salesforce without creating custom visualforce pages? The only issue is, I would like the users to be redirected to a custom web page as opposed to 
https://test.salesforce.com/

Is there an admin setting I could change?
or,
is it possible to create a new custom button on the standard layout on the top that does this (and of course, hide the current Logout link that references /secur/logout.jsp)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using out of the box configuration. If you were using Communities it can be configured - See [Add Custom Login, Logout, and Self-Registration Pages from the Winter 15 release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_networks_custom_pages.htm).

Otherwise your options are to:

- try and manipulate the /secur/logout.jsp link with a `retUrl` parameter. I suspect the retUrl will need to be within the Salesforce domain.
- use the API [logout](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_logout.htm) methods.

Without official support attempting to change the Logout link be a hack and error prone.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'manipulate the /secur/logout.jsp link with a retUrl parameter' please? How/where could I do this?

Comment: You could present your own logout link, perhaps in the sidebar. The other, much less desirable approach is to try and inject Javascript into every page that can manipulate the DOM. I really wouldn't recommend that approach. See [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/38918/102)

Comment: If we create a custom logout link in the sidebar, how do we hide the standard logout link? Having both is confusing and defeats the purpose.

Comment: I don't believe there is a supported way to hide the standard logout link. You will need to resort to injecting Javascript to manipulate the DOM. The link in the previous comments point out problems with such an approach.

Comment: So there is no clean and easy way of doing this at this time. Thanks for your inputs, Dan.