# Hide Recycle Bin from Home page using VF component (summer 15 release)

Tags: recycle-bin, summer-15

As Salesforce has removed all HTML components after Summer 15 release. I have used it on Home Page COmponent to Hide "Recyecle Bin".

Can anyone please advice, how can we acheive this fucnttionality using VF component or any other solution to this problem?
Its very urgent.

Thanks
Dharmendra

Comment: Why do you want to hide the recycle bin ? Let's try to solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

That method is no longer possible and I don't believe there is a workaround at the moment.

However, I would question the entire approach as it seems hackish to me. For example, what's preventing someone from accessing the Recycle Bin by directly navigating to the URL of the page?

Firstly you should manage the permissions related to the Recycle Bin correctly:

> - To view and recover your deleted records:  “Read” on the records in    the Recycle Bin
> - To view and recover records deleted by other users:    “Modify All Data”
> - To recover deleted public tags:    “Tag Manager”
> - To purge the Recycle Bin:  “Modify All Data”

The full article is [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_delete.htm&language=en_US).

If you absolutely must hide records after they enter the Recycle Bin there are better options available. For example:

- Create a trigger on the necessary objects which prevent them from being undeleted
- Create a trigger on the necessary objects which updates the record ownership when they are deleted, making the record owner a private user / queue etc.

Comment: There is still a workaround available. See [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds) for details, but that workaround is only good till Winter '16

Comment: Thanks BarCotter.
Solution is not working :( I have not find anything till now.