# How To Automatically Remove Empty Home Page Component?

Tags: home-page-component, cross-domain

Before the latest updates, we were able to use **`Javascript Post Messaging`** from a `VisualForce Home Page Component` in order to hide it when empty. For example:

```
if({!someCondition}) parent.postMessage('empty', '*' );
```

This strategy doesn't work any more, which leads me to believe that `Post Messaging` is now broken from embedded `VisualForce`. It doesn't seem like it should be affected by cross-domain issues for [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging), but I wonder if that may be in play? I am using a version that lists support.

The solution we have dreamed up, but have not yet started to implement, is to write a batch/trigger that essentially checks `{!someCondition}` and if it is false, we use the Metadata API to hide the `Home Page Component` from the `Home Page Layout`.

**Is there still a way to conditionally hide a Home Page Component in real time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this essentially ended up being a dupe of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds#answer-41840), we needed to add the listener using the methods described. Note the `Javascript` gets executed twice.

To remove a `VisualForce Home Page Component` whose `ApexPage` has Id '066XXXXXXXXXXXX':

```
(function (w) {
    "use strict";
    w.addEventListener("message", function () {
        var body = document.getElementById('bodyCell'),
            toRemove = document.getElementById('066XXXXXXXXXXXX');
        if (body && toRemove) body.removeChild(toRemove);
    });
})(window);
```