# Showing alert for a user assigned a task

Tags: visualforce, tasks, notification, popup, task-notifications

I'm looking for a way to show an alert / a notification / a popup or similar for the user which has been assigned a `task`? It should be nearly real time, that is if user have browser window open it must be shown instantly after the task has been assigned. ***Is it possible at all?*** *Alternatives?*

I assume it has something to do with the `triggers`, programming `apex class` and designing a `view` in the `visualforce`?

Could someone put me on the right path please?

I'm not new to various programming paradigms, just not sure where or how to start in the salesforce.

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar challenge.  When we reassigned a record, we needed to have the new owner receive an email notification AND and mobile notification on their phone (near instantly).

Our solution was a Trigger/Flow which would create a Chatter Post on the record on behalf of the user that changed owner, like:

> @[userName], this lead has just been assigned to you.  Please follow-up within the next 24 hours!

This approach did 3 things, without any code

1. Push Notification received on mobile device, for salesforce1 users
2. Email notification set to employee's email, since there was an @Mention
3. Chatter Feed acted as an audit trail, and allowed easier communication/response with management.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a `Home Page Component` (narrow) and the `Streaming API`.

Your `PushTopic.query` would look something like:

```
'SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE OwnerId = \'' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '\''
```

Not sure if you want a different lookup field but that's the idea. Whenever your listener picks up an insert, you can kick off whatever popup you want.

You might want to look into [this approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds#answer-41840).