# Salesforce and JS framework

Tags: angular, angularjs

I just want clear answer, someone told me that using JS framework on salesforce is being discouraged. What and Why?

By the way AngularJS is a JS framework and it's on Dreamforce Video.

Comment: They may have been referring to the [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds) rather than the use of JavaScript in custom pages.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever told you that is wrong. As you can see by that Dreamforce video as well as the new features that are coming in each release (e.g. Lightning Components) are heavily focused on JavaScript.

Also there are blog posts like [this one](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/02/visualforce-javascript-knockoutjs-rolodex.html) on the official Salesforce blog related to JS Frameworks, which means Salesforce and the community are supporting those.

Obviously there is a lot of functionality coming out of the box with VisualForce, but when it comes to UX and performance, JS is a must. I encourage you to go ahead and utilise those frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2015/02/future-salesforce-development-javascript/) is a very good blog post about the future of JavaScript in Salesforce by  JEFF DOUGLAS.

The last line summarizes the article well "Start learning Javascript today. It’s the future."

Answer (score 0):

The original poster isn't totally wrong. SalesForce has dicouraged at times the use of other frameworks because they can interfere with Lightninig. Loading a framework inside a framework can create issues:

- Two frameworks to download and bootstrap
- Lack of communication (or a manual maintenance) and numerous issues with events and routing
- Conflicts with CSS
- Rendering issues (for example, every time you are routing to another page, you will boostrap the second framework).

Still, there are use cases for it, for example you might want to display a widget on a page where the user spends more time without reloading the page.