# Disable future dates in the Salesforce date picker?

Tags: visualforce, datetime, date

Is it possible to disable future dates in the Salesforce date picker? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do in a complicated way using visual force and custom date picker. However I feel the best way to write a validation rule upon save to save if the selected date is in future or not, and throw the error respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If VF page is not an option, [This](http://www.codebycody.com/2011/05/fix-for-salesforcecom-date-picker-year.html) can help you out which actually increases the years, you can tweak the code to decrease. But since Salesforce may not support Javascript in sidebar , you might have to combine with [this approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds) !!