# How can I create a tour like this for my product?

Tags: community

Customers are not able to understand the flow of my product. what are the various mechanisms to create tours such as this one?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use that feature out of the box. Of course, you could build some Visualforce pages, assuming you can hook into the pages you want, but it's all up to you. There's no API here that will help you, no way to provide you're own custom guide without writing it all yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3rd-party products - here is [one](http://salesforce.walkme.com/) example and [another](https://iridize.com/salesforce-onboarding-optimization/) example (this is not a recommendation of either and you should Google for others) - that provide tools to author help and walk-though content and hook it into the Salesforce desktop.

However, they used to make use of JavaScript in the sidebar that Salesforce is in the [process of eliminating](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds). So if such a product looks like it might meet your needs you should check with the vendor how they intend to work around that platform change.