# Salesforce Winter 16 Link Home Page component workaround alternative

Tags: force.com, sidebar

I have been using the Salesforce Home page component workaround and later the links workaround explained here:
[End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)

I have tested this in a winter 16 org and it no longer works. Salesforce have changed the way they include the JavaScript on the page and they require the user to click on your link exposed in your home page component before your script referenced with "INCLUDESCRIPT" is included on the page.
Is anyone aware of a new workaround to inject JavaScript on standard VF pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Salesforce is revamping the UX completely from winter '16. There would be no workaround until the release reaches to real ground level devs.

Comment: there's a workaround. let me just document it...

Comment: pnoytechie - did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: please let me know if there are any workarounds