# How to disable standard home page component

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to disable home page component like below code:

```
    if(UserName == 'Abc'){            
       **document.getElementById('hPendingProcessWorkitemsList_title').disabled=true;**
       }else if (UserName == 'bcd'){
          **document.getElementById('homeCalendarSection').disabled=true;**
    }
```

but I am getting null value on highlighted section.

Am I doing any thing wrong?
I am using this java script code in vf page which I will add in home page.

Thanks

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is hard to do now and may be impossible in Spring '16. See [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to hack javascript.

Each Profile can have a different [Home page layout](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=designing_home_page_layouts.htm), configured by the System Administrator.

If you want User 'Abc' to see something different from 'bcd' then create a different profile for each. In defining the profiles it might help to ask yourself *why* you want them to see different Home layouts.

Comment: That's good suggestion but I can not create new profile.