# Override the 'Approve/Reject' button

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, page-layout, approval-process

Is there anyway I can override the 'Approve/Reject' button with a VF page so that when I click on the button, I'm taken to a page where I can enter custom data?

There seems to be no documentation on this and this post [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds) says that Javascript sidebars don't work from Winter '16.

Does this have any relevance? If not, please do help!

Comment: Could you please explain how I can do that?

Comment: Here's the deal. I have no clue what I need to do and I'm not finding any documentation for this. I need an approval process where I need to have custom fields so that I can enter data there. To do this, I need to override the 'Approve/Reject' button with a vf page that has those custom fields. How to do that, I don't know. 

And this is to be done on the 'Home' tab and not in the related list

Comment: User2529 You can't override the links

Comment: Anything else I can do?

Comment: check this workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779714/how-can-we-overide-an-approve-button-in-approval-related-list  ... Also check this http://technicaladda.blogspot.in/2015/07/hide-approvereject-link-on-approval.html   Also  http://www.salesforcetutorial.com/hide-approvereject-links-home-page/