# Injecting Javascript into Standard Page

Tags: javascript, winter16

I have a standard page that i have been injecting javascript into. It is using requirescript to require static resources in salesforce. This saturday we updated to salesforce 16 and it has stopped automatically running this code. I can click on the custom link and the the JS will run. Is there another work around for this that i can implement or a salesforce standard i can use?

The end goal is to add a drop down menu that groups all related custom buttons together into one menu that on hover shows the related buttons.

Any help would be appreciated, leave a comment if more information is needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no longer supported (and has been coming for quite a while), you will have to find a different solution I'm afraid.

> You can include JavaScript in your Visualforce page, but because the component is rendered in an iframe on the home page layout, the JavaScript can’t interact with the page that contains the component.

[SFSE discussion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)

Comment: I've been coming accross this alot. This is really disappointing for how simple this should be. We have too many buttons on our pages, there should be an option to group these....