# Hiding "Save and send update" button on event edit page layout

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, event

I'm using below JS code to hide "Save and Send Update" button , but it's not working

```
function hideBtns(){
if(document.getElementsByName("sendEmail")[0]!=null)
    document.getElementsByName("sendEmail")[0].style.display = "none";
if(document.getElementsByName("sendEmail")[1]!=null)
    document.getElementsByName("sendEmail")[1].style.display = "none";
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", hideBtns, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", hideBtns);
}
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what error do you see on console?

Comment: I'm not getting any error , but it's not hiding the button

Comment: Do you know how to use console in chrome? try executing  document.getElementsByName("sendEmail")[0].style.display = "none";  If it does not found sendEmail[0] it will show error. Try same thing in [1] if its does not find both then that could be reason of your issue.

Comment: From where this hideBtns fuction is getting called?

Comment: I am adding to home page component and then adding it to home page layout

Comment: But how to embed this js script into edit event layout

Comment: See [End of javascript sidebar workarounds](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds/41840#41840).

Comment: my JS code is working when I'm testing in console . I'm not able to embedded it to home page layouts as HTML area is not supported by salesforce after Summer 2015 release .

Answer (score 0):

what about giving an Id to those buttons and hide it in style.

```
#your_id{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That is a std button like new and save...its not an vf page