# Override or remove del link from action column in the related list for Activities

Tags: related-list, activities, delete, action

I've created a visual workflow that will allow users that has custom permission to delete activities (calls, emails...) and a delete custom button have been created to trigger the flow and override the standard delete button. However, I also need to override the del link in the related list in order to prevent users that don't have custom permission to delete activities. Is there a way to override or remove the del link option from the action column in the related list or I really need to create a VF page to prevent the deletion? Suggestions?

Comment: you could also do a `before delete` trigger and catch the delete action that way

Comment: Hi cropredy! Thanks for the comment. So, can I do it in the flow? How? I'll appreciate if you can give me more details about how can I do that.

Comment: You can override the standard delete action on both the related list and the  detail page's Delete button with a VF page that could launch a flow.

Comment: The standard delete button was override for a custom one and the flow is working. We just need to adjust the del standard link in the action column in order to prevent activities record deletion. :) Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Does anyone have any good resources on how to prevent users from using the del standard link in the action column in order to prevent AccountContactRelationship record deletions? It seems like a VF page is the way to go, but as I am not versed in VF or APex, can anyone *pleeeease* help?? Thank you, MG

Comment: @Tony Ther's no other way for now, VF page is required in order to hidden the del link and prevent user from record deletion. I've found other trick, maybe can help you: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D0PrAAK
My best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to overwrite the entire related list with a `Visualforce Page`. It used to be able to be possible by injecting stylesheets and scripts and the like, but that has been disabled for some time.

See also: **[End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)**