# Is it possible to show pop-up at regular intervals on standard edit page layout of an Object

Tags: javascript, popup, edit

If a user is on standard edit page of an object,is it possible to show a pop-up at regular intervals let's say 5 mins to remind users to save the record.

So far,

I have created custom edit button and executing javascript

`window.open('/{!Study_CELG_IPS__c.Id}/e');`

`setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);`

`function myFunction() { 
  alert('Hello');
 }`

this is opening edit page in new tab and pop-up is showing after 3s but in detail page tab.

If I use `window.open('/{!Study_CELG_IPS__c.Id}/e','_self');` then pop-up is not working.

Comment: do you get any javascript error in the console when inspecting the page?

Comment: There was no error displayed,on clicking custom Edit button,it simply opened edit page layout and it did not invoked any pop-up after 3s.

Comment: This is a javascript issue. The script will run on the page where it was called. You might want to check javascript forums for possible solutions (I'm not an expert), e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043887/how-to-execute-javascript-jquery-on-a-newly-opened-popup-screen and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open/3030893#3030893

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using any of the currently (sept '16) available Salesforce technologies.

You could do it with a javascript workaround as described here: [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)
That's definitely not for newbies, though..

My advise would be to educate your end users to not forget to save.. Or you could put up a warning message in a formula field, and put that at the top of the page layout (ugly, though).

Comment: Guy,I have updated my approach so far in question,is there any workaround that could be done in order to achieve this